# Time delay in method delaying whole program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two methods, for example, delayloop() and function(), where delayloop() has a while and time() delay to loop it every n seconds.

If in my main, I call:

```
delayloop();
```

then

```
function();
```

The method function() is never called, as the looping method before it seems to prevents it.

What is the method to prevent the application from not passing the delayloop() function?

Edit:

delayloop();

```
void delayloop() {
boolean delay = true;
while (delay){
    time_t start_time, cur_time;

         time(&start_time);
         do
         {
                time(&cur_time);
       }
      while((cur_time - start_time) < 5);   

 cout << "+5 seconds" << endl;

}   

}
```

Comment: Show the code of your delayloop function

Comment: "where delayloop() has a while and time() delay to loop it every n seconds."  To loop *what*, every n seconds?

Comment: @Fox32 @FredOverflow @Stéphane delayloop() code added.

Comment: You never set `delay` to false, hence we enter an endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal conditions, control flows sequentially through your program. If you enter an endless loop before the `function()` line, then `function` is never going to get called. So it would seem you have an error in the `delayloop` function, and it would help is if we could see the code.

There we have it. You never set `delay` to false, hence we enter an endless loop.

Comment: How is it possible to repeat a function every minute, for example, while other code in the program is executed? Thankyou for your help.

Comment: @Jez You need to use threads to do that. Basically you tell your function to start each time your timer expires (every N seconds or whatever suits you), and it runs in an independant flow. see http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/C++Programming-HOWTO-18.html for more info (many other tutorials available through a google search)

Comment: @Jez: By using multiple threads. Which is not something you want to get into right now if today is your first day of learning C++, if I remember correctly from the chat.

Comment: Ahh thanks guys. And yes, it is my first day of learning. In a few days maybe! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

replace the `while` loop by a `for` loop in delayloop().

(assuming the exit condition for the while loop is never met, and you would correct that in an easier to understand for loop... but this is a long shot without seeing the code and understanding the goal of these two functions)

Edit after you added the code:

The first `while` condition is always true (`delay` is not modified), this is why it blocks. replace it by an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

you are never changing the state of delay, so it will always stay true and the loop will be executed indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You never change `delay`; there is no way out of the loop. It's hard to advise you how to change it, without knowing what you *want* `delayloop()` to do.